# Pass a URL as a get parameter in php

Tags: php, url, get

```
   http://example.com/geturl.php?url=http://example.org/index.php?parafile=1698%3A1562%3A0%3A0&para_action=print_ticket&parafile=dance://here.kodas/print&token=3ec2b0d3e6e0ca152bc024cc3f30f16c
```

So i want each of this parameters in a different varaible in the geturl.php file. I am using the regular get url

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this? Post your code.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use anything like this :

```
$url = "http://example.com/geturl.php?url=".urlencode($urlPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

$_server[QUERY_STRING] solved my problem